# Migration Spring security 3.x to 4.x specifically form-login

Tags: spring-security

I have been assigned a task to migrate application from Spring security 3.x to 4.x. I am following the guidelines on spring official website [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html). I am stuck on 1 specific part related to form login. I am getting access denied error when I try to login into the application with no idea how to debug the issue. The security config is mentioned below.

EDIT: updated with complete http block

```
<sec:http auto-config='true' create-session="ifRequired" disable-url-rewriting="false" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <sec:headers disabled="true"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/e/fileupload/*/showFile" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/e/reports/clearing/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/e/reports/participants/*/export"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER', 'HOST', 'PLANER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/e/reports/participants/*/export/true"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER', 'HOST', 'PLANER')"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/rest/participant/*/toggleCheckedIn"  access="permitAll" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/cancellationInvoice/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/cancellationParticipants/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/cancellationResult/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/cancellationSummary/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/cancellationSendMail/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER')"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myes/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER', 'PLANER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR', 'BACKOFFICEUSER')"/>
    <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="moreeAuthenticationHandler" authentication-details-source-ref="moreeWebAuthDetailsSource" login-processing-url="/myes/j_spring_security_check"
         username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password" login-page='/login' authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1" default-target-url="/myes/home" always-use-default-target="false" />
    <sec:logout        success-handler-ref="moreeLogoutHandler" invalidate-session="false" logout-url="/myes/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    <!--  Handlerklasse referenzieren -->
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="moreeAccessDeniedHandler" />

    <sec:session-management>
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/session-timeout.jsp"/>
    </sec:session-management>
</sec:http>
<!-- Login mit entsprechenden Rollen ermitteln  -->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Teilnehmer Authentication -->
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    <!-- myEvents Authentication -->
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <sec:salt-source user-property="username"/>
        </sec:password-encoder>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: can you share application logs please ?

Comment: @coder I have set the log level to info, however nothing is printed on console.

Comment: Updated with complete http section